# How can I display the details in another activity when Cardview is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem, how can I display the value of the `cardView` based on its position? I feel like I am kinda missing something.

here is my code

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AnnouncementViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AnnouncementModel announcement = announcementList.get(position);

        if (announcement.getImage()!=null && !announcement.getImage().isEmpty()){
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(announcement.getImage())
                    // To fit image into imageView
                    .fit()
                    // To prevent fade animation
                    .noFade()
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }else{
            //Do nothing
        }

        holder.textViewDate.setText(announcement.getDate());
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(announcement.getTitle());
        holder.textViewExcerpt.setText(announcement.getExcerpt());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return announcementList.size();
    }

    class AnnouncementViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewExcerpt,textViewDate;
        ImageView imageView;

        public AnnouncementViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementDate);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementDesc);
            textViewExcerpt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementDesc);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.AnnouncementImageView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivityAnnouncement.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

I want to display the `textViewDate` and `textViewTitle` to my other activity when click.

Here is my `detailActvity`

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "position";
    AnnouncementModel model;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_announcement);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        int postion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);

        TextView announcementContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementContext);
        TextView announcementDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementDate);
        ImageView announcementImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AnnouncementImageView);
        TextView announcementOtherDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementOtherDetails);


    }

}
```

I feel like I am already close to my answer but I am still stuck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What position you are receiving in the detail activity.

Comment: index 0. it is the length of the my cardview.

Comment: You have to pass the data which you want to use in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intent to send data from one activity to another.

In your `itemView.setOnClickListener()` you already defined the Intent to open your `DetailActivity`.

Now all you need to do is add data with intent like

```
Context context = v.getContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivityAnnouncement.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());

// putExtra can be used to send data with intent, here "date"
// and "title" is key that we will need later to access these values 
intent.putExtra("date",announcementList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDate());
intent.putExtra("title", announcementList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());

context.startActivity(intent);
```

In your `DetailActivity` you can retrieve this information in your `onCreate` method

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_announcement);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        int postion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);

        //you can retrieve data from intent like
        String textViewDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
        String textViewTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

        TextView announcementContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementContext);
        TextView announcementDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementDate);
        ImageView announcementImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AnnouncementImageView);
        TextView announcementOtherDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnnouncementOtherDetails);


    }
```

**Extra:-** you should always check that you have received data from intent and make sure `textViewDate, textViewTitle` is not null.

you can also check before retrieving data in activity like `if(getIntent().hasExtra("date"))` if you have data then it will be true.

Comment: thanks sir! but is this really the right way? or the best practice to do it?

Comment: @JanessaBautista, no, it's not the best way but it's the most basic way to send data.
as you see here we sending one or two data, as you specified in the question. but if you need more data then it's better to send whole object like
`putExtra("AnnouncementObject",announcementList.get(getAdapterPosition()))`

but you have to make `AnnouncementModel` class either `Parcelable` or `Serializable`

Comment: can this affect the performance of the app? by using the getIntent.hasExtra?

Comment: @JanessaBautista i don't think it have any significant effect on performance. but yes sending data one by one and retrieving them one by one is time consuming task to write code .

Comment: @JanessaBautista Just a suggestion, if you are just starting out on Android and in learning Phase, i suggest you to make basics more solid for now like `Intent, Activity,View` etc.
best practices are not any definite way, it vary by developer and circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of passing just the position to the detail activity you should try passing date and title in the intent(instead of just position) and then get both of them in detail activity to display it OR you can make your announcement object **parcelable** and then pass it in the intent itself that way you can get all details. you can set a tag to the itemView
using `itemView.setTag()` and then get the object using `itemView.getTag()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make an interface

```
public interface DeviceClickedInterface {
void DeviceSelectedInterface(int position);
}
```

and in your Adapter pass it to the Class

```
private DeviceClickedInterface deviceClickedInterface;

public DevicesAdapter( DeviceClickedInterface deviceClickedInterface, ... the rest of params.) {
    //other params. init.
    this.deviceClickedInterface = deviceClickedInterface;
}
```

make the `AnnouncementViewHolder`contains the `itemView` as child too, and inside the `onBindViewHolder` add `ClickListener` on the `itemView`

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> deviceClickedInterface.DeviceSelectedInterface(position));
```

at last make the `DetailActivity` implements your own `DeviceClickedInterface` and it will Override `DeviceSelectedInterface` method in your Activity which will return the position each time you click on a `CardView`